# Is there a bug in Android Pie for NFC Tag connection?

Tags: android, nfc, android-9.0-pie

I made an app, which connects to a NfcV tag to read and write it's connected EEPROM.

```
    NfcV nfcV = NfcV.get(tag);
    try {
        nfcV.connect();
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }
```

All works fine for devices with `Android` < 9.0. On devices with Android Pie, an IOException occurs, which - after further debugging - is caused by a

> ErrorCodes.ERROR_CONNECT (-5).

Do you have any idea what I can do to make it run on Android Pie devices?